# How to use Youtube Video Ads in the Youtube Android Player API?

Tags: android, youtube-api

The [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html) that announces the new Android Video Player API states that the API is supporting YouTube ads. However in the documentation there is nothing about this ads.

How are YouTube ads incorporated in my App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the owners of the video have requested ad's and allowed embedding, the ad's will play.  The owner of the content is who get's paid.

If you own the content, you can mark your content for ad's and allow embedding, and you'll get paid.

Comment: Is the ad also played if I play the video in a simple VideoView? Sadly this results in a very bad video quality.

Comment: No - VideoViews don't play ad's.  The reason for the API is to access the higher quality video.